# Not able to get Python 2 environment in Jupyter Notebook after creating and activating in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Working on my Windows machine, I installed Anaconda 3 and created a Python 2 environment in Anaconda Prompt using commands below:

```
conda create -n py2 python=2
activate py2
conda install numpy matplotlib pandas scikit-learn
```

However, when I run `jupyter notebook` in Anaconda Prompt, in the opened notebook, I checked Python version using this:

```
import sys
print('Python version is:', sys.version_info)
```

I found out it is Python 3 instead of Python 2...I wonder what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need to install jupyter notebook like below in Anaconda Prompt as well, otherwise, the default Python 3 version notebook will be called.

```
conda install jupyter notebook
```

Now, if we launch jupyter notebook again, we'll get Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You may also find that you need to install the Notebook extensions which provides Conda environment and package access extension from within Jupyter Notebook. You can do that by running:

```
conda install nb_conda
```